# Is there any way to use biometric sensor to show your fingerprint ins Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-biometric

As the title says the question is the next one: So, is there any way to use biometric sensor to show your fingerprint in Android Studio?

The reason of my question is because some time ago I was completing some forms and I needed my fingerprint to complete it, I don't have a fingerprint reader at home, but my phone has one. I was trying to find an app, but didn't find any. So, I had to wet my finger with ink and then press a paper to get my fingerprint. I think there has to be a way, so Can anyone of you help me with it? This code will be for personal use.

Beforehand thank you very much...

Answer (score 1):

No that is unfortunately not possible. The only thing the fingerprint sensor does is to (depending of the technology the sensor is using) measure the conductivity of your fingerprint and decode it into an own model. It can't optically save your fingerprint.